# Explicit Conformal Mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

**The Question is:**

Find an explicit conformal mapping mapping the region : {$z \in \mathbb C | |z| \lt 2 , Im(z) \gt 0$} to the upper Half-plane: $\mathbb H^{+}$ ; such that under that mapping $f$ (say,) ; $f(i) = i$ .

**My Effort & Difficulty**:

Call the region : {$z \in \mathbb C | |z| \lt 2 , Im(z) \gt 0$} to be $A$ . Now via the mapping $f_{0} (z) = \frac {2+z}{2-z}$ ; $A$ is mapped to the first quadrant. Then via the mapping $f_{1}(z) = z^{2}$ ; first quadrant is mapped to the whole upper Half-plane: $\mathbb H^{+}$ .TILL HERE I AM CLEAR.

Now, for sending $i$ to $i$ under $f(z) = f_{3}(f_{1}(f_{0}(z)))$ ; I have observed that : $f_{1}(f_{0}(i)) = \frac {(-7)+24i}{25}$ . So, I have to find a self map of upper Half-plane: $\mathbb H^{+}$ , which is of the form $f_{3}(z) =e^{i\phi} \frac {z-a}{z- \overline a}$ which sends $\frac {(-7)+24i}{25}$ to i . Please provide me how to do it in detail. Thank You!

**N.B.**: I know if I know the image of three points under a Fractional Linear Transformation (F.L.T.) , then I can find the F.L.T. explicitly. Please show me how to employ that fact here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula for the analytic self-map of the U.H.P. isn't correct, your formula is for self-maps of the unit disc. Note that if $a$ is not real, then either $a$ or $\bar{a}$ is in the U.H.P., and it is sent to $0$ or infinity, respectively; if $a$ is real, $f_3$ is just a rotation around $0$, which except for the trivial rotation isn't a self-map either.)

If a complex F.L.T
$$f: z \mapsto \frac{a z + b}{c z + d}$$
maps the real line (plus the point of infinity) to itself, then we may as well take $a, b, c, d$ to be real (as usual, so that $f$ is bijective, we have $ad - bc \neq 0$). Your condition has the form $f(z_0) = z_1$, so we are looking for coefficients $a, b, c, d$ such that
$$z_1 = \frac{az_0 + b}{cz_0 + d}.$$
A convenient way to solve this would be to rewrite this as
$$a z_0 + b = z_1(cz_0 + d)$$
and decompose both sides into real an imaginary parts, a process which is made simpler in your case because $z_1$ is imaginary.

Comment: Ooops..I am sorry.. I mixed up the self maps of $\mathbb H^{+}$ ... For the second part, from the relation $f(\frac {(-7)+24i}{25}) = i$ ; as you mentioned I am getting two equaitons : $-7a+25b = -24c$ & $24a=-7c+25d$ ... But there are four variables. So, how to get them from here??

Comment: You can simply pick any solution you like (that satisfies $ad - bc \neq 0$. Note that scaling all of $a, b, c, d$ by the same factor gives the same map, so a F.L.T. only depends on three parameters (in fact, the group of analytic bijections $\mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{H}$ is isomorphic to $PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$). The solutions to the two equations you've produced thus comprise a one-parameter family of F.L.T.s. But this is expected: there is a one-parameter family of F.L.T.s that preserve the real line and that map $i \mapsto i$, and these are just the "rotations" of $\mathbb{H}$ around $i$.